# Disable GoogleTalk auto-start/spawning

Tags: google-talk

I just installed Google Talk using the official google .deb [here](https://www.google.com/tools/dlpage/hangoutplugin/download.html), however the process stays always. Since I don't like to have a google app always open on my system, I'd like to disable it when I don't use it, and disable the auto-start, do you know how I could do that ?

I tried to manually kill it, but it just re-open a few ms after...

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What have you installed exactly?

Comment: @CelticWarrior : I just installed the official .deb here : https://www.google.com/tools/dlpage/hangoutplugin/download.html

Comment: It's a complement for Google Hangouts and probably that's the one you see running.

Comment: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/hangouts/_9zWU5M7Bt8